# Keep track of Window being Last Focus

Tags: vb.net, winforms, focus

The VB.Net program I am creating dynamically created Panels within a `TableLayoutPanel` and adds form elements to them.  I need to keep track of what the last of these Panels to have focus was, and am hitting a bit of a brick wall.

I have tried creating an event class for when the Panel has focus:

```
Private Sub Self_GotFocus(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles Me.GotFocus
    GlobalController.Focus_Target = Me.Name
End Sub
```

The classes for each Panel Inherit from `Windows.Forms.FlowLayoutPanel`, which I why I have the call being `Me.GotFocus`.  Additionally, the `GlobalController` class is just a class meant to hold global variables for the program.

Now the issue I am having, is that this event only seems to trigger when I actually am deleting the panel.  When the panel is created, if I click on it, or any of it's form elements, the event never gets triggered (I debugged the program with a breakpoint).

I can't exactly figure out why this only triggers when I go to delete the panel, and not at any other time.  Is there another event I should be using instead of `GotFocus`?

Answer (score 0):

Use `.Enter` event in your panel since GotFocus is related only to focused control (not it's parent), mostly when UICues is set.

See [MSDN GotFocus](https://msdn.microsoft.com/cs-cz/library/system.windows.forms.control.gotfocus(v=vs.110).aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)

Comment: `.Enter` seems to work a bit better than `GotFocus` but it still isn't exactly what I am looking for.  For example I'd like to be able to have the focus variable change when I click in the Panel Area, as opposed to just clicking on the elements within the panel.

Comment: Panel is a container control and it cannot get focus (using click or Tab key). You need to handle your ClickEvent or change style to Selectable using Me.SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, true) depending of your overal desing.

Comment: Thank you.  I was about to figure it out using a ClickEvent

Comment: A custom control derived from `Panel` can be focused on mouse click (or by tabbing). You just need to use its [SetStyle Property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.setstyle?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev15.query%3FappId%3DDev15IDEF1%26l%3DEN-US%26k%3Dk(System.Windows.Forms.Control.SetStyle);k(TargetFrameworkMoniker-.NETFramework%26f%3D255%26MSPPError%3D-2147217396&view=netframework-4.7.2)): `SetStyle(ControlStyles.Selectable, True)`.